# Move record to another table then delete it Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, roles

Hi I have a problem here, i want too move it to another table then delete it from the first table.
It moves the record but not the specific one, it moves the data consecutively from the list. Also when clicking the archive button it display this error but still working on the localhost(not dispalying the list):

ErrorException
compact(): Undefined variable: archiveStudentData

Controller:

```
public function archiveData(){
    $archiveStudentData = User::where('role', ['athlete'])
        ->each(function ($oldPost) {
            $newPost = $oldPost->replicate();
            $newPost->setTable('archives');
            $newPost->save();
            $oldPost->delete();
            return view('users.admin.pages.archive-student-list', compact('archiveStudentData'));

        });
```

Routes:

```
    Route::get('archive-student-list', [AdminController::class, 'archiveData'])->name('archive-student-list');
```

Comment: return view after end of each `});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put your Return like this:

```
public function archiveData(){
    $archiveStudentData = User::where('role', ['athlete'])
        ->each(function ($oldPost) {
            $newPost = $oldPost->replicate();
            $newPost->setTable('archives');
            $newPost->save();
            $oldPost->delete();
        });
    
    return view('users.admin.pages.archive-student-list', compact('archiveStudentData'));
}
```